# React share information between Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 2 components.

First I will call of **Father**

```
<Main>
  <ChartDoughnut />
</Main>
```

First I will call of **Child**

```
const data = {
    labels: [
        'Red',
        'Green'
    ],
    datasets: [{
        data: [300, 50],
        backgroundColor: [
        '#FF6384',
        '#36A2EB'
        ],
        hoverBackgroundColor: [
        '#FF6384',
        '#36A2EB'
        ]
    }]
};

class ChartDoughnut extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <Doughnut data={data} />
            );
        }
}
```

Very basic. Ok?

But I would like send some informations like: Labels and datasets.data; for my chart, from **father** to **child**, but I have no idea how I can make my component understand this parameters to fill with correct information.

Comment: show us the code for Doughnut, at least show you tried to render the data passed as the data prop.

Comment: I agree with you that this question is very basic.  You should do some research in the documentation before asking a question here.  I would start with this article: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. But you should accept one of the answers using the green checkmark, or you should add an answer yourself with a piece of code. And you may want to upvote helpful answers. The link to the youtube tutorial is not adapted to a question, but you may add it to your own answer if you have a complete answer to provide.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Doughnut labels={data.labels} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send what are called props ([Docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)) from the parent component to the child component.

```
<Main>
  <ChartDoughnut data={[300, 50]} backgroundColour={[
'#FF6384',
'#36A2EB'
]}>
</Main>
```

In the child this appears as `this.props` so in the above example you could use it like this:

```
datasets: [{
  data: this.props.data,
  backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColour,
  hoverBackgroundColor: [
    '#FF6384',
    '#36A2EB'
  ]
}]
```